# Distinct function with Criteria

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, criteria

I want to execute this query with Criterias but it seems is not working as expected:

```
SELECT DISTINCT descripcion, id, familia_id, numero_departamento FROM familia WHERE familia_id IS NULL GROUP BY descripcion;
```

I have tried this

```
public List getFamiliasPadre() {
        Criteria cri = getSession().createCriteria(Familia.class);
        cri.add(Restrictions.isNull("familia.id")).setProjection(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("descripcion")))
                .setProjection(Projections.groupProperty("descripcion"));
        return cri.list();
    }
```

But it returns a result like if I were executing this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT descripcion FROM familia WHERE familia_id IS NULL GROUP BY descripcion;
```

It only returns column descripcion.

My question is, How can I tell Hibernate that I want all columns of my table but I don't want to repeat vaules from descripcion column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just can't do that in plain SQL queries. I mean, how can you possibly merge 2 rows that only share one column? For example, imagine this is your table:

- familiaId - descripcion - otro
- 1) null - algo - foo
- 2) null - algo - bar

There's no way DISTINCT can apply to just one column and leave the rest aside, because you are expecting to have only one row for those two rows.

Comment: I'm not merging two rows, I'm just applying the function Distinct to one column, it works fine it brings all the records which are unique but the problem is that only brings one column (descripcion) and i Want all columns of the table. I don't know if I gave it to misunderstand.

Comment: So let me understand, what you want is getting all the rows that have a unique value for the `descripcion` column? If there are two rows with the same value for that field you don't want any of them?

Comment: I'm really sorry, the one who misunderstood was me, but What do you mean to leave the rest aside? I only want to "delete" the repeated values for my query.

Comment: Yeah, but your only repeated value is the description column. `SELECT DISTINCT` compares all the columns you are returning. If you add all the columns in the query, you are going to get all the rows. I hope it makes sense what I'm trying to explain. By merging I mean that, in my example, you are going to get rows 1 and 2 because they are different, because there's no way you could combine both to apply some kind of `DISTINCT`. Otherwise, what value would you get for the column `otro`, the one coming from the first row or the one coming from the second?

Comment: Got it, I think now that I will have to work with java code instead of bringing the values I need with the query, beacuase I will also need some values from the column numero_departamento. I knew that it couldn't be that easy. Thanks for your help by making me figure out that.